# Refresh ASP.NET ListView from Event handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

So, I have an event that is fired always when a text file is updated. This is the event handler:

```
private void FileWasChanged()
    {
        this.runsList.Items.Clear();
        runningModels = RunsFile.ReadFile(Constants.active_runs_loc, Constants.run_file_name);

        this.runsList.DataSource = runningModels;
        this.runsList.DataBind();
        this.updatePanel.Update(); 
    }
```

Within this method I am clearing the ListView (runsList), reading the contents of the file and then binding the new data to the ListView. The updatepanel is then updated. But that does not happen, the page stays static until I press F5. Here's the layout:

```
         <section>
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManager1" runat="server" ></asp:ScriptManager>
            <asp:UpdatePanel id="updatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:ListView ID="runsList" runat="server">
                    <LayoutTemplate>
                        <ul>
                            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
                        </ul>
                    </LayoutTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <li>
                            <asp:Label Text="<%# Container.DataItem %>" runat="server" />
                        </li>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:ListView>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="runsList"/>
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </section>
```

So I am trying to give the user of the web site real time information from the text file. For example, when I change a line in the text file, that line should be added to the web page. The event itself works fine (tested with break points and console project), but for some reason the async update does not do anything.

I tried to look for similar problems, but everyone is using a button for the asyncpostbacktrigger. However, I am very new to C# so I may be misunderstanding how UpdatePanel and ListView DataBind work.

Any help appreciated!

Cheers,
Tetsii

**Edit**: The FileWasChanged is a handler that is called from FileSystemWatcher OnChanged event. The handler updates the view if called from Page_Load or an async button trigger.

Comment: Where/how the FileWasChanged handler is called? Is it in a different update panel, or somewhere else on the page?

Comment: Its called from FileSystemWatcher OnChanged event. In short, it fires each time the file is changed. When I set a breakpoint on the .DataBind() I can see the updated items, but the list seen on the page does not update (eg. No refresh happens)

Comment: So you have a watcher against some file, and this runs locally on your server, and then you want to update a page whenever this watcher fires? Without actual request from the page? If so, this is not going to work without a lot of additional effort from your side. By default updates on the page (client) are initiated by clients only by doing requests. So you cannot just update page from the server without client doing a request for update. There techniques to work this around though (checkout what COMET is)

Comment: Exactly! Okay I see. Of course I could be horrible and create some timed poller that fetches new data every 0.5 seconds, but thats exactly what I tried to avoid in the first place. I also keep bumping into SignalR. Is this something I could use? Ill also look into COMET! Thanks a lot.

Comment: SignalR should definitely help you here, give it a try